# Google sign in crashes on IOS but works fine on Android

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

i have all the research i made still yet immediately i click on google to sign in the app will crash.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.390674890211-klbqki2me0m8fjccmbkt..........</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb36858607......</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

here is my declearation

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'profile',
  ],
  hostedDomain: '',
  clientId: '',
);
```

i have try this too but still crashing

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
  hostedDomain: '',
  clientId: '',
);
```

pubspec.ymal

```
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

flutter run -v file

[flutter run -v file](https://file.io/SvaWJXGRcgto)

error message

```
PlatformException(google_sign_in, You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|, NSInvalidArgumentException, null)
```

Comment: What do you get in error message?

Comment: yes...google_sign_in, You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|... this is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone is having this same issue that is why i have to answer for future reference.

here is the link that solve the problem

[the github link solve the problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82464)